# Why does a TToolBar calculate button widths automatically when ShowCaption is set True?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I need to have two `TToolBar`s on the right side of my main form, so I put three `TPanel`s for alignment, and then put the `TToolBar`s inside them. I've been trying to tell the `toolbutton`s to have the same width for the past day, to no avail. Here's a screen shot of what I've got:
[image]

I found out that if `ShowCaption` is set to `True`, the toolbars calculate the button width automatically. My question is why, and how to disable this?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this approach:

1. Set Autosize to False for all buttons.
2. Call the following inside Form’s OnCreate event: `SendMessage(ToolBar3.Handle,TB_SETBUTTONWIDTH, 0, MAKELPARAM(0, <DEFAULT_WIDTH_THAT_YOU_WANT_TO_SET>));`
3. Make sure you do not alter the Visible property of any buttons before the above call – as it will fail for those buttons that are not visible.
4. Also, ensure you have “CommCtrl” in the uses list for TB_SETBUTTONWIDTH message.

For more details: http://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/ttoolbars-ttoolbutton-autosize-width-issues-empty-caption/

Answer (score 0):

the width of the buttons is calculated according to the width of the text of the longest caption of the TtoolButton

Answer (score -2):

You can use object inspector to set the button width with static value, or you can use formcreate or onpaint or onresize etc to set the value dynamically........

Comment: `ButtonWidth` reverts to the value `TToolBar` calculates

Comment: I know that. I can't set it because it reverts to the value the toolbar has already calculated for it

Comment: ya you are right i went through the comctrls i noticed it is coded to reflect so, few properties in ttoolbar like buttonwidth,buttonheight etc is the width/height of the ttoolbutton component,so when u change the width or height in either ttoolbar or ttoolbutton that will influence the other......

Comment: So, the question is, how to set `ButtonWidth` when `ShowCaption` is set to `True`.

Comment: setting the property grouped of ttoolbutton to true will give you uniform width for all the buttons in the same ttoolbar....... no idea about for different tool bars......

Comment: @Anto, whoa, please don't suggest to change a width in the `OnPaint` event. That's freaking bad!