# How to set exact Height of TToolButton at design-time?

Tags: delphi, toolbar, delphi-10.1-berlin

In a Delphi 10.1.2 VCL application, I have a `TToolButton` on a `TToolBar`:

```
object tlbDocProperties: TToolBar
  AlignWithMargins = True
  AutoSize = False
  Left = 1
  Top = 28
  Width = 422
  Height = 28
  Margins.Left = 0
  Margins.Right = 0
  BorderWidth = 1
  ButtonWidth = 148
  Color = clBtnFace
  DoubleBuffered = True
  EdgeInner = esNone
  EdgeOuter = esRaised
  Images = cxImageList16Bookmarks
  Indent = 5
  List = True
  ParentColor = False
  ParentDoubleBuffered = False
  ShowCaptions = True
  TabOrder = 0
  Transparent = False
  object btnEditDocProps: TToolButton
    AlignWithMargins = False
    Left = 5
    Top = 0
    Height = 22
    Down = False
    AutoSize = False
    Caption = 'Edit Document Properties'
    ImageIndex = 56
    Style = tbsCheck
    OnClick = btnEditDocPropsClick
  end
end
```

Whenever I try to change the Height of the `TToolButton` at design-time from 22 to 24 it automatically snaps back to 22. I have tried many different settings both for the `TToolButton` and for the `TToolBar` at design-time but it always snaps back.

So how can I change the Height of the `TToolButton` at design-time from 22 to 24?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a trick which works as a perfectly practical solution:

Instead of using a 16x16 icon for the `TToolButton` I use a 16x18 icon from a 16x18 ImageList (Width = 16, Height = 18).

Now the height of the `TToolButton` automatically snaps to 24 as desired!

To set the button to the desired height modify the canvas height of the glyph in an icon editor by adding a number of transparent pixels at the top and the bottom of the glyph, for example:

[image]

Using the above `TToolBar` example, I have derived this empirical rule from several tests:

```
Button Height := Image Height + 6
```

This means: With a glyph height of 18 you get a button height of 24, and with a glyph height of 20 you get a button height of 26, etc.

Remember: This works only with the above configuration, i.e. when `ToolBar.List = True` and `Toolbar.ShowCaptions = True`. And of course, you need a `ToolBar.Images` ImageList where `ImageList.Height` matches the glyph height.

Comment: I want to use 16x18 glyphs and have button height of 26. How do I do that. That is the question asked. Can you answer that.

Comment: Simply use glyphs with a relevant height. Change the canvas size of the glyphs by adding a transparent area at the top and bottom of the glyphs.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question that was asked.

Comment: I won't let me provoke this time :)

Comment: @user1580348 Nice catch. I never imagined that by changing ToolButton icon size you could also affect the size of the button itself. I will try to remember this trick as it could come in handy someday.

Comment: Thanks, but remember this works only with the given configuration, i.e. when `ToolBar.List = True` and `Toolbar.ShowCaptions = True`.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the `Show Caption` property of `TToolBar` as it can cause the buttons to be resized according to the caption size

[TToolBar.ShowCaptions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.ShowCaptions)

You can also read about one possible solution for your problem here

[Why does a TToolBar calculate button widths automatically when ShowCaption is set True](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32998424/3636228)

Note that you can also use other buttons like standard `TButton` or `TSpeedButton` on `TToolbar` by placing them manually. Both of them allows you to show their captions without the need to use `TToolBar.ShowCaptions` property enabled but they do look different.

**EDIT:** Another solution for increasing the TToolBar button's height to 24 is to increase the `TToolBar.Font.Size`.

When using `Tahoma` as Font I had to increase the size from 8 which is default to 11 to have buttons height 24.

So play around a little with Font size to find proper value for yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, these otherwise smart bits of advice do not work in my case as I need the captions on the buttons. When I switch `ShowCaptions` off on the toolbar I can set the button height to 24, but as soon as I switch `ShowCaptions` on again the button height automatically goes back to 22. I cannot use other buttons because I have several toolbars in the app which should all be the same visual style. And I cannot increase the font size either, as that would make the button caption looking very ugly.

Comment: Even when I use a `TSpeedButton` on the toolbar it always snaps back to a height of 22!

Answer (score 0):

Have the toolbar in a panel.
Set the panel Font size and type to whatever you like.
In the Toolbar, set the Parent Font to "True".
The Toolbar button size will automatically adjust to be consistent with the font of the panel in which it resides.
Then just adjust the font size and type of that panel until you get the toolbutton size you require.
You do not need ShowCaption on or Off in the toolbar. It doesn't matter.
regards
Graeme